# OrderbyDescending on date does not order as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have below `NotificationViewModel` designed:

```
public class NotificationViewModel
{
    public string NotificationText { get; set; }
    public DateTime Moment { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
}
```

and I am generating my Notification data as below:

```
List<NotificationViewModel> model = new List<NotificationViewModel>();
int days = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Sunday;
DateTime weekStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-days);
DateTime weekEnd = weekStart.AddDays(6);

var purchases = await context.tbl1.Where(x => x.created_date <= weekEnd && x.created_date >= weekStart)
                .Select(x => new NotificationViewModel()
                {
                      Icon = "fa fa-gbp",
                      Moment = x.created_date,
                      NotificationText = "A new purchase.",
                }).ToListAsync();
model.AddRange(purchases);

var stocks = await context.tbl2.Where(x => x.created_date <= weekEnd && x.created_date >= weekStart)
               .Select(x => new NotificationViewModel()
               {
                      Icon = "fa fa-cubes",
                      Moment = x.created_date,
                      NotificationText = "A new stock",
               }).ToListAsync();
model.AddRange(stocks);
var sales = await context.tbl3.Where(x => x.created_date <= weekEnd && x.created_date >= weekStart)
               .Select(x => new NotificationViewModel()
               {
                      Icon = "fa fa-shopping-cart",
                      Moment = x.created_date,
                      NotificationText = "A new sale",
                }).ToListAsync();
model.AddRange(sales);

model.OrderByDescending(x => x.Moment); 

//The above line does not order items according to their occurrence
```

I've also tried as below:

```
model.OrderByDescending(c=> c.Moment.Date)
.ThenBy(c=> c.Moment.TimeOfDay);
```

But even that did not work and model remained same.. How would I go sorting with this data? Any insights is much appreciated..

Comment: model = model.OrderByDescending(c=> c.Moment.Date)

Comment: You should reassign the result of OrderByDescending to the model

Comment: have you tried to assign to a variable, like var ordered = model.OrderByDescending(x => x.Moment) ?

Comment: Awesome.. Quick solution.. Thanks much guys.. :) @Steve

Comment: FYI, `IEnumerable` instances are *read-only* by design. This means that no operation will modify the original enumerable, but rather create a new one.

Comment: @MatiasCicero Thank you for that.. :) Will keep in mind.. :)

Comment: Downvotes for what?? :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the method `OrderByDescending` returns a new sequence and doesn't order the sequence in-place. So you need to :

```
model = model.OrderByDescending(x => x.Moment).ToList();
```

Alternatively, you can sort the list in-place using:

```
model.Sort((x, y) => y.Moment.CompareTo(y.Moment));
```

It is worth noting that based on the documentation, `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending` are stable Sort methods (Original order in the sequence is preserved if two items have an equal sort order) , while the `Sort` method is documented as an unstable Sort.

Comment: Thanks much for the solution and more information on other things... :) Will be accepting the answer soon.. :)